# How to pause service without using stopService() method?

Tags: android, service

This is MainActivity, also I have Service class working fine.
All i need is to pause my MediaPlayer and don`t know how to do it at my activity.
When I call stopService it fully stops and how to use pause then?

```
public class MainActivity extends QuizActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
        }

        public void stopClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
        }

        public void playClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as i know no activity can live forever, as Android destroys even paused activities to reclaim RAM.So this may be the same case with services too.In case activities you can use `moveTaskToBack(true)` for pausing the activity.Not sure about services though.

Comment: look into [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/8NFRnnI1KpA) which talks about "Ability to use the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON intent to play/pause/next music"

Comment: You need to bind to the `Service` which will then allow your `Activity` to directly call methods in the `Service`. See the following link... https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Thanks, maybe that is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: The TrivialDrive sample app includes code that binds to a service, in case you would like a working example.